# android sharedpreferences set value

Tags: android, preferences

I have preferences page. It has field 'Show info screen' (as checkbox).

I have also info page which also should have checkbox 'Show me again'.

As I've understand, I can get value from preferences page via `PreferencesManager.getDefaultPreferences(context)` ...

But how I should set preferences value for the checkbox on info page?

I tried to use `context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, 0).edit()`, to set value but it doesn't correlate with PreferencesManager's corresponding value.

What should I do??? F1

Answer (score 120, accepted):

It depends on whether you are after one set of preferences for your application, or one set per activity.

I've used code like this:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putBoolean(PREF_NAME, false);
editor.commit();
```

and

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
if (prefs.getBoolean(PREF_NAME, true)) {
    // etc
}
```

Comment: +1 for a great answer. I would emphasize that `Editor` is **not** a modal visual editor waiting for user interaction. It's simply an atomic way to do the opposite of `SharedPreferences.getString()`.

Comment: use apply() instead of commit() will do it in the background.