# How to disable particular options on Android 4.4 and higher?

Tags: android, sms, android-4.4-kitkat

My app works with incoming SMS (asks if it is spam or not and react accordingly).

With [Android 4.4 implementation](http://android-developers.blogspot.ru/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html), my app shouldn't be able to

1. to abort the SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION broadcast;
2. write to the SMS Provider.

How could I determine android version and disable (a) according Preferences, (b) according code?

Comment: Afaik with android 4.4 there can only be one app that reads sms so Im not sure if your approach work e.g. my sms backup app needs to bw set as primary sms if i want to backup temporary

Comment: @for3st, this is exactly what I've said in my question (see also the link I gave).

Answer (score 1):

You can check for the version at runtime like so:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    //Do stuff here. (Or don't)
}
```

All version codes can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html).

From: [Supporting Different Platform Versions](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/platforms.html#version-codes).

Comment: Thanks! Can I use it at `Preferences` class `onCreate` method? What is the right way to change default preferences value (for ex., if it is `false`, but should be `true` for KitKat?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You can use this wherever you want to disable or tweak certain features of your app. The `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` is the current version of the device and you're checking if that is greater or equal to KitKat.

Comment: I tried to use `setDefaultValue` and direct edit of the preference like `edit.putBoolean("my_pref_key", false);`, but it doesn't help.

Comment: Yes, I got how to check the version. But the question is related to the preferences update based on the version.

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3328562/1449972) what you are looking for? Although it looks like that was what you did ;)